# Why are my fonts rendering so horribly in Chrome in KDE?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, fonts, chrome, plasma5

[image: Chrome tabs]

I have anti-aliasing enabled with slight hinting. The system font is Ubuntu, including serif, sans and mono fonts. The Chrome font is Roboto.

It works just fine in GNOME.

I've also noticed that bold fonts don't render nicely either.

[image]

[image]